# Looking for an Array formula based on certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking for a formula for the following table;

[image]

What I would like ideally is for column T8:T21 (will need more rows eventually) to consolidate a list of any 'Carton No' from Column M, based on the criteria from Column P showing as 'DELETE LABEL'. I'm not great with Array Formulas but I'm pretty sure this is what is needed in this case. Just ping if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

With the Dynamic Array formula available with Office 365 subscription or later:

In T8 put:

```
=FILTER(M:M,P:P="DELETE LABEL")
```

And the results will spill down automatically.

Comment: Hey Scott, I tried to do this but my version of excel appears to only have FILTERXML as a usable formula, will this work in this format or not?

Comment: @TimIsherwood no, FILTERXML is a different formula, you will need to use `INDEX(...,AGGREGATE(15,7,...))`

Comment: Hey Scott sorry to be a pain can you help me put that into a format I can use straight up on the sheet above for example for lets say a 10 cell range.